# The kernel of the derivative linear transformation $d(x) = 5q''+3q'$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation in the polynomial spaces $ d(q) = 5q''+3q' $. I'm looking for an elegant way to show that the dimension of the kernel  is 1. I know that the constant
polynomial is in the kernel but have can I show this is the only basis for the kernel ?

Thanks!

Comment: $5D^2+3D=0$ gives the complementary function as $y(x) =a+b e^{-\frac 35 x}$ but $e^{-\frac 35 x}$ is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

For a polynomial $q,$ let $ax^n$ be its highest degree term with $a \neq 0,$ and assume $n \geq 1$ Then $5q''$ won't have any terms of higher degree than $n-2,$ and so the $3anx^{n-1}$ term in $3q'$ won't be cancelled by anything. So, $d(q) \neq 0$ for any polynomial which is not constant.